# ASP.net API response, doesnt return json

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, react-native, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a react-native app with an express.js backend. Now I wanted to create an asp.net (WebApi) backend for this app. Both have the same endpoints, but the response from the asp.net backend doesnt work in react-native. The response.json() gives me promise and not the json value.

I already changed the return type of my controller, but nothing changed. If I query the api with PostMan everything looks right.

In the app:

```
   fetch(`${URL}/job/load/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                const result = response.json();
                resolve(result);
            });
```

Controller:

```cs
   public object Load(int job) {
       bool exist = DoesJobExist(job);
       return Ok(new { exist = exist });
   }
```

The result should be `{ exist: true }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021870/fetch-returns-promise-instead-of-actual-data-even-after-using-then

Comment: Thanks you! Why is the second `.then()` not necessary when I receive the data from express.js? Because it is not async?